# VBA extract and parse data from website to Word

Tags: vba, parsing, ms-word, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract some data from here: http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f140215.dat

This is the exchange rate list from the Croatian National Bank. The file name "f140215.dat" is basically a date, formatted in the following order:

"f" "DDMMYY" ".dat"

I intend to have the data organized in a Word table, which contains the following cells:

- Cell#1 where a user would manually input a date in the following
  format: "MMM DD, YYYY"
- Cell#2 where a user would manually input the requested currency code
  name (USD, GBP, etc)
- Cell#3 where the extracted exchange rate should appear for the
  specified date and currency.

Underneath the table there is an "UPDATE" button that updates the Cell#3 information. The script I'm asking for should be connected to that button.

After clicking the button, I'd like the script to do the following:

- Figure out which page to go to based on the date inputted in Cell #1.
  For example, if the Cell#1 contains "February 14, 2015", the script
  should point to "http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f140215.dat"
- On that page, grab the middle value for the currency specified    in
  Cell#2. For example, if Cell#2 contains "USD", the script should
  extract "6,766508" which is the middle value for "840USD001". Only
  the middle value is relevant.
- Write this value to Cell#3.

So to sum it up, based in the criteria specified in the two table cells, the script needs to identify which page to go to and what data to extract from it, and with that data populate the third cell.

Hope I explained it well enough. This is only a part of the whole invoice generator I'm building. So far I've gotten everything to work, but this I really don't even know how to start. I can send the whole thing if needed, but figured it's not exactly relevant.

EDIT:

I watched some tutorials and played around, and this is what I got so far.

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub Test()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f140215.dat"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = ie.document

MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerText

End Sub
```

I know it's not much, but like I said, I'm new at this. I was able to get the data into the message box, but I have no idea how to parse it, and without that I can't really do anything mentioned above. What now?

EDIT 2:

Alright!! Made some progress! I've managed to parse it by using the split function:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f140215.dat"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set html = ie.document

Dim getData As String
getData = html.DocumentElement.innerText

'replaced all the space fields with line breaks
Dim repData As String
repData = Replace(getData, "       ", vbCrLf)

'used line breaks as separators
Dim splData As Variant
splData = Split(repData, vbCrLf)

MsgBox splData(1)
MsgBox splData(2)
MsgBox splData(3)

End Sub
```

Right now it displays the parsed data in message boxes. The rest should be easy!

**Addendum from OP's comment:**

This is a part of the continued code:

```
Dim cur As String
cur = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("valCombo").Item(1).Range.Text
If cur = "USD" Then
  ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text = splData(40) & " HRK"
End If
If cur = "EUR" Then
  ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text = splData(20) & " HRK"
End If
```

This way it works, but I'd like to set `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text` as a string. However, once I do that, it doesn't do anything. Why is that?

Comment: Parse the date into a *fddmmyy.dat* format then use one of the flavors of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and parse the `.responseText` to get what you need. When you've demonstrated some original effort, come back and edit the software specification you've written above to include your own attempt at programming, specifying any errors that you have received.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks for the pointers, but I think I'm still far from the point where I need to use them. I edited the post above, so please have a look when you get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it! See EDIT 2 :-)

Comment: I think you are getting pretty close. Congrats on recognizing the use of `Split` of the raw output. See my version below that uses many of the same methodology but in a different context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you with the first half of your project; that being the retrieval of the data. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, data retrieval such as this is better suited to an `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTT` type of object.

You will have to go into the VBE's Tools ► References and add **Microsoft XML v6.0**.

```
Sub scrape_CNB()
    Dim u As String, dtDATE As Date, xmlHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim sTMP As String, sCURR As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, vLINE As Variant, vRATE As Variant

    On Error GoTo CleanUp

    Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    sCURR = "USD"
    dtDATE = CDate("February 14, 2015")
    With xmlHTTP
        u = "http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f" & Format(dtDATE, "ddmmyy") & ".dat"
        .Open "GET", u, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .send
        If .Status <> 200 Then GoTo CleanUp

        sTMP = .responseText
        vLINE = Split(sTMP, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
        For i = LBound(vLINE) To UBound(vLINE)
            If CBool(InStr(1, vLINE(i), sCURR, vbTextCompare)) Then
                Do While CBool(InStr(1, vLINE(i), Chr(32) & Chr(32))): vLINE(i) = Replace(vLINE(i), Chr(32) & Chr(32), Chr(32)): Loop
                vRATE = Split(vLINE(i), Chr(32))
                For j = LBound(vRATE) To UBound(vRATE)
                    MsgBox j & ": " & vRATE(j)
                Next j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

    End With

CleanUp:
    Set xmlHTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Since you are not initiating a full Internet.Explorer object, this should be much quicker and the `.responseText` that is returned is raw text, not HTML.

TBH, I find the cursor position based VBA programming within Word to be hard to deal with; preferring the one-to-one explicitly defined relationship(s) with an Excel worksheet. You may want to consider using Excel as a data repository and merging with Word to provide your invoice output.

**Addendum:**

```
Dim cur As String, t as long, r as long, c as long
cur = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("valCombo").Item(1).Range.Text
t = 1: r = 7: c = 3
Select Case cur
  Case "USD"
    ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Cell(r, c).Range.Text = splData(40) & " HRK"
  Case "EUR"
    ActiveDocument.Tables(t).Cell(r, c).Range.Text = splData(20) & " HRK"
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks! One problem though... I tried to run it real quick and got a Compile error "User-defined type not defined" with "Set htmlBDY = New HTMLDocument" highlighted.

Comment: I did! Still happening!

Comment: My apologies - I had that in and then removed it (see above). That line is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Ok, I decided to do a mix of your and my method. One question though.. This is a part of the continued code:

`Dim cur As String

cur = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("valCombo").Item(1).Range.Text

If cur = "USD" Then
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text = splData(40) & " HRK"
End If

If cur = "EUR" Then
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text = splData(20) & " HRK"
End If`

This way it works, but I'd like to set **ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(7, 3).Range.Text** as a string. However, once I do that, it doesn't do anything. Why is that?

Comment: As soon as you convert the document, table and cell references to a string, they lose all relevance, becoming text that looks like a reference. You will have to assign some variables (maybe *t, r* and *c*?) and use them to define the table no, row and column. A `Select Case` looks like it would be better that a series of If/End If's. See above. If further edits and clarification are needed, it may be better to start a new question on this second half of the project with the latest versions of everything.

Comment: Aaah, got it! 'Select Case' is also very nifty vs IFs! Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jeeped, can you please have a look at my new question regarding this project? You'll probably know best since you've in the loop. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551983/vba-date-minus-x-days-from-today