# VBA - date minus X days from today

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here's a snippet of my invoice generator, particularly the crawler SUB that grabs the exchange rate from a webpage who's URL contains the exchange rate date. I'm trying is force it to go to a URL from Saturday if the referring date (datIzd, pulled from datIzdCtrl content control) is Sunday or Monday, because the page isn't yet generated on those days. Currently Sunday and Monday send out "out of range" error.

Perhaps a much better way would be for the date to keep going 1 day back until it hits a page that exists (and notifying in MsgBox how far back it went), because the same thing applies to holidays - bank doesn't release the new exchange rate, so the one from last working day is relevant.

Can someone show me how this is done? I tried using

```
If Weekday(Now(), vbMonday)
```

and playing around with it, but it didn't get far.

Also I'm aware that in the code I'm seemingly unnecessarily reformating dates multiple times, but this is a must since US and Croatian date formats aren't the same, and they have to be properly presented on respective invoices, and recalculated for URL name between conversions.

Here's what I have.

```
Dim splData As Variant

Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Sub Crawler()

    Dim url As String, datIzd As Date, xmlHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim getData As String

    Set xmlHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("datIzCtrl")(1).Range.ParentContentControl.DateDisplayFormat = "MM-DD-YYYY"

    datIzd = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("datIzCtrl")(1).Range.Text

    With xmlHTTP
        url = "http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f" & Format(datIzd, "ddmmyy") & ".dat"
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .send
        getData = .responseText
    End With

    repData = Replace(getData, "       ", vbCrLf)
    repData = Replace(getData, "      ", vbCrLf)
    splData = Split(repData, vbCrLf)

    If OptionPredracun.Value = True Or OptionRacunPredujam.Value = True Or OptionRacunUkupniIznosHR.Value = True Then
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("datIzCtrl")(1).Range.ParentContentControl.DateDisplayFormat = "DD. MMMM YYYY."
    Else
        ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("datIzCtrl")(1).Range.ParentContentControl.DateDisplayFormat = "MMMM DD, YYYY"
    End If


End Sub
```

Note: if this sounds confusing, you can have a look at my previous post regarding this same project that goes into more detail on what I'm trying to do:

[VBA extract and parse data from website to Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517857/vba-extract-and-parse-data-from-website-to-word/28522759?noredirect=1#comment45370228_28522759)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear on what type of variable *datIzd* is. The assignment to the `.Text` property of the form seems that it is a *String* but its later use in the `.Format` function makes it look like a *Variant* or *Date* type. In the following, I'll declare it as a *Date* type and use `DateValue` (another option is `CDate`) to convert the content control's text to an actual date.

```
dim datIzd as date
datIzd = DateValue(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("datIzCtrl")(1).Range.Text)
```

Once you have an actual date in *datIzd*, you should be able to determine its `Weekday` and subtract the weekday from the date if it is Sunday or Monday. The default vbSunday is probably best for this as that makes Sunday a *1* and Monday a *2*.

```
if Weekday(datIzd) < 3 then
  datIzd = datIzd - Weekday(datIzd)
end if
```

A more simplified version of that uses VBA's perceived values of *-1/0* for *True/False* like this.

```
datIzd = datIzd + ((Weekday(datIzd) < 3) * Weekday(datIzd))
```

This should all be done before *datIzd* is used to create the URL string in,

```
url = "http://www.hnb.hr/tecajn/f" & Format(datIzd, "ddmmyy") & ".dat"
```

Either of those should push Sunday and Monday back to the previous Saturday. Tuesday and later will be left alone.

Comment: Damn, you're good. Can you  explain the third code field (the simplified one)? Maybe it's just the math thing, but I can't quite understand how it works.

Also, all I need now is to figure out how to return it to the last existing date if I accidentally go too far in the future, or if it's a holiday when bank doesn't work. I'll try that on my own and let you know if I don't succeed. Once again, well done and thanks!

Comment: Hi @blackwind - As mentioned, VBA thinks *True* is *-1* and *False* is *0* (aka *zero*) when used mathematically. If `Weekday(datIzd) < 3` is false then we are multiplying the weekday by zero which results in zero so we are adding nothing to the date. If `Weekday(datIzd) < 3` is true then we are multiplying -1 against the weekday. For Monday this means a result of -2. If we want to reach the previous Saturday, we need to add -2 to the current date. Same goes for Sunday and -1. FWIW, on the worksheet, TRUE is 1, not -1 but FALSE is still 0.